# Intersection of ordered collection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, that's why I am struggling with pretty basic question I think. I have two lists:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

On the output I need to get all the intersections between them:

```
c = [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

What's the algorithm for that?

Comment: Isn't your output supposed to be `[1,2,5,6]`?

Comment: I am guessing by your output example of `c` that you want the extrema of ranges that exist as intersections, is that right?  What would be your expected output if a 3 was included in `b` as well?

Comment: if 3 was included in b, I would expect:
    c = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [difflib.SequenceMatcher](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) for this purpose

```
#Returns a set of matches from the given list. Its a tuple, containing
#the match location of both the Sequence followed by the size
matches = SequenceMatcher(None, a , b).get_matching_blocks()[:-1]
#Now its straight forward, just extract the info and represent in the manner
#that suits you
[a[e.a: e.a + e.size] for e in matches]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant, because this will work both on sorted and on all ordered sets, even if these are not sorted... and respect the sequencing!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) which supports intersections in python

`s.intersection(t)  s & t   new set with elements common to s and t`

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
b = {1, 2, 5, 6}
a.intersection(b)
set([1, 2, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

use sets:

```
In [1]: a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [2]: b = [1, 2, 5, 6]

In [4]: set(a) & set(b)

Out[4]: set([1, 2, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a lambda expression for this:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b = [1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> intersect = filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
>>> intersect
[[1, 2, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This would work for sorted sets, but this might not hold for all ordered sets, would it?

Comment: Intersection doesn't imply order.

Comment: Agreed, though the question was about lists not sets. But you have a good point anyway.